# RegularExpression RegExp.test

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a string with following regular expression -

```
^\d{4}-\d{5}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$
```

which is regex for a zip code with 4 digits-then 5 OR 6 digits after dash.

I am hoping my regex is correct as I have tested it on some online RegEx tester.

and for matching my string with above regex in jquery, I am using:

```
var regExpTest = new RegExp("^\d{4}-\d{5}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$");  
alert(regExpTest.test("1234-123456"));
```

But I am always getting false, can anyone please guide what is going wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: It's always useful if you type `new RegExp("^\d{4}-\d{5}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$")` in the console and see it's output. E.g. in this case you'd get `/^d{4}-d{5}$|^d{4}-d{6}$/` which shows that the expressions tries to match literal `d`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the regular expression constructor takes a string as its argument, you need to escape the backslash `\` wherever you use it.  In your example, anywhere you have a `\d` needs to be `\\d`.  You can see what happens if you don't by testing your code in Firebug or Chrome's developer tools:

```
new RegExp("^\d{4}-\d{5}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$");
//-> /^d{4}-d{5}$|^d{4}-d{6}$/
```

Notice the slashes are gone?  Now watch what happens when we escape each backslash:

```
new RegExp("^\\d{4}-\\d{5}$|^\\d{4}-\\d{6}$");
//-> /^\d{4}-\d{5}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$/
```

So that should fix your problem.  However, it's much easier to use the literal grammar for regular expressions when you're not using a variable to create them:

```
var regExpTest = /^\d{4}-\d{5}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$/;
alert(regExpTest.test("1234-123456"));
//-> "true"
```

This way, you can write the expression without having to worry about double-escaping.